# Can I use partial dependency plot for lmer model?

Tags: plot, dependencies, lme4, partial, interaction

Can I use a  Partial dependency plot for lmer model using the stats package or another package? I want to plot partial dependency for continuous interaction predictors to visualize the interaction effect of predictors on response variables.

I used an effect plot but it was not promising.

This paper "pdp: An R Package for Constructing Partial Dependence Plot" introduces packages for different models although there was no package for lmer i used the package (stats) for glm and it worked. The partial dependency plot worked but I am not sure whether can be applies to lmer or not

This is the code I used:

partial(out1, pred.var = c("T", "F"), plot = TRUE, chull = TRUE, train = data, type = "regression", xlim=c(0,20))

Can you please help me?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.